# Awk slower than lz4 decompression

Tags: awk, bigdata, throughput, lz4

I have half a million files with 290 MB each that mostly consist of numbers.
I'd like to (routinely) filter through this data, but find that awk is slower than decompression.
For example,

`/usr/bin/time unlz4 bigfile.lz4 --stdout > /dev/null
0.20user 0.05system 0:00.44elapsed 57%CPU`

`/usr/bin/time unlz4 bigfile.lz4 --stdout | awk '{if ($26>120.) print}' > /dev/null
0.25user 0.25system 0:01.35elapsed 37%CPU`

Notes:

- Before each timing, I cleared the page cache.

  The size of the output data is small and not relevant. In this excercise the output is discarded altogether.

  `awk` here is `gawk 5.0.1` on Ubuntu.

  Tried `mawk` instead of `awk`. It didn't make a difference.

  I wrote a C program that reads the data with `fscanf`. It was significantly slower than `awk`.

  I tried reading from HDD and SSD. `awk` is slower than `unlz4` for both.

  Each `lz4` file has about 66 MB (compressed from 290 MB).

  Using uncompressed files is even slower. `cat bigfile | awk '{if ($26>120.) print}' > /dev/null`

I conclude that it does not help to use a fast decompression format like `lz4`, instead of stronger and slower compression formats, because even the simplest filtering with `awk` will be the bottleneck.

Does anybody have any insight or bright ideas about this? Is there a way to speed this up or have I hit the physical limit?

Comment: what exactly are you doing to your data?

Comment: @IgorRivin Eventually, I will replace `/dev/null` with `output.txt` to store a subset of the data.

Comment: No, what TRANSFORMATION or filtering are you applying.

Comment: @IgorRivin  I'd like to find all entries where column 26 is larger than 120. But this is just a generic examples. I'd like to filter according to the values in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your files are small enough that startup time is a significant contributor to your runtime. Simply put, `unzl4 | anything > /dev/null` is always going to take a little bit longer than `unlz4 > /dev/null` because both ends of the pipeline need to start before processing can happen. So measuring a larger time for the pipeline case doesn't *necessarily* mean that the consumer is slower than the producer, or that your choice of compression algorithm is irrelevant. If you want to measure the impact of changing your compression algorithm, change your compression algorithm, and measure it!

Comment: I have already tested nine compression formats, and chose the fastest one in this example. My question is not about decompression, but about how to accelerate the throughput after decompression.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I merged two 66MB `lz4` files and measured the time for decompression + awk filter. It takes twice as long.